# Access is denied. When i try CRUD XML files using XAML for windows 8

Tags: xml, xaml, windows-8, crud

It doesn't throw this error everytime, thats what makes it strange.
I got 50% chance that it works.

This is how I call the save method

```
private async void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await settings.WriteSettings(settings);
}
```

And this is the method itself

```
public async Task WriteSettings(Settings settings)
{
    var ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings));
    var writer = new StringWriter();
    ser.Serialize(writer, settings);
    dom.LoadXml(writer.ToString());
    StorageFolder sf = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    StorageFile st;
    st = await sf.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting); // here i get the error
    await dom.SaveToFileAsync(st);
}
```

I hope you guys understand the problem and you can help me getting a solution

Comment: Here you go homeboy, check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk3w6240%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the reason why i get Acces denied when i try to Acces a file more than once.
It's because i didn't close the file after using it.

This is how i acces files now:

```
public static async Task WriteSettings(Settings settings)
    {
        StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        var stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();

        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings));
        ser.Serialize(stream, settings);

        await stream.FlushAsync(); // This
        stream.Dispose(); // And this helped me solve my problem
    }
```